# Obtain Key from a Hash of Arrays using array value

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

I have a Hash as follows:

`{'a' => [title: 'ab', path: 'cd'], 'b' => [title: 'ef', path: 'gh']}`

Now lets say I have one title and wish to get the key from it...

i.e. if I have 'ef' and want 'b'

This is what I'm currently doing, but it seems extremely clunky...

```
def get_hash_key(hash)
  hash.each do |k, h|
    return k if h[0][:title] == 'ef'
  end
end
h = {'a' => [title: 'ab', path: 'cd'], 'b' => [title: 'ef', path: 'gh']}
get_hash_key(h)
```

Is there another better way of doing this?

Comment: @sawa Sorry I'm confused, what do you mean that it isn't a valid ruby object - it works in irb

Comment: @sawa its basically a hash within an array within a hash

Comment: I see. You omitted the hash within an array.

Comment: Surprise, surprise! ` [title: 'ab', path: 'cd'] #=> [{:title=>"ab", :path=>"cd"}]`, at least in Ruby 2.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
h = {'a' => [title: 'ab', path: 'cd'], 'b' => [title: 'ef', path: 'gh']}
h.select { |_,v| v[0][:title] == 'ef' }.keys
# => [
#   [0] "b"
# ]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
h = {'a' => [title: 'ab', path: 'cd'], 'b' => [title: 'ef', path: 'gh']}
  #=> {"a"=>[{:title=>"ab", :path=>"cd"}], "b"=>[{:title=>"ef", :path=>"gh"}]}

h.each_with_object({}) { |(k,v),g| g[v.first[:title]] = k }['ef'] 
  #=> "b"
```

or

```
h.each_with_object({}) { |(k,v),g| g[k] = v.first[:title] }.invert['ef']
  #=> "b"
```